# Error with iOS driver set up

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

As per the instruction with http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/?page=setup ,  i am trying to set up ios driver my application first testing using this automation. 
I have installed java 7 and downloaded the app in given link. Installed OSX 10.9. While executing the command `$ java -jar ios-server-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar -aut path/to/aut.app -port 4444` i am getting below error

`45:08:315 INFO ApplicationStore.<init>  App archive folder:/Users/labuser/Downloads/applications
false`
`45:08:838 SEVERE IOSServer.main  cannot start ios-driver server:     org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: path/to/aut.app isn't an IOS app.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown`

Any one suggest me to resolve this error and am new to use commands in terminal

Comment: It looks to me like `path/to/aut.app` is a placeholder and you need to replace it with the path to your application

Comment: yes solved thanks. i did mistake in app path

Comment: @Paul: for safari testing i have completed the setup upto updating  the MobileSafari Info.plist and the java code to be execute is given. Could you please let me know where to execute and how to start mobile safari? only the java code given and not given where to execute

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know anything about this framework - I was just editing your question for clarity and noticed the path error.  Perhaps this will give you some clues - https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver/issues/188

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `path/to/aut.app` is a placeholder and you need to replace it with the path to your application.